# Bookpagination in Biblatex-chicago

Tags: biblatex-chicago

Under biblatex, if an @incollection entry had no bookpagination field, this would be understood to have a default value of "pages", and where necessary the page range would be preceded by *p.* or *pp.*. However, in biblatex-chicago this is no longer the case:

> This, a standard biblatex field, allows you automatically to prefix
>   the appropriate string bookpagination to information you provide in a
>   pages field. If you leave it blank, the default is to print no
>   identifying string (the equivalent of setting it to none), as this is
>   the practice the Manual recommends for nearly all page numbers.

(From the biblatex-chicago manual, p. 24 http://ctan.math.washington.edu/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex-contrib/biblatex-chicago/doc/biblatex-chicago.pdf)

Is it possible to change this, so that the default behaviour is again to put in "p." or "pp." (i.e. to have the default be "pages" rather than "none")? I could of course go through my (now very long) bib file and add in an explicit line

```
bookpagination = "pages",
```

to every @incollection item, but this would be inefficient. Is there any way to do this globally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Standard `biblatex` defaults to `bookpagination = {pages},` if no `bookpagination` is given. `biblatex-chicago` avoids this and essentially falls back to `bookpagination = {none},` by adding a test to the field format. We can remove this test and go back to the standard behaviour.

The MWE retains the `biblatex-chicago` format for `@article`s, but you can get "p."/"pp." there as well by simply removing the `\DeclareFieldFormat[article,periodical]{pages}` block.

```
\documentclass[american]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[notes, backend=biber]{biblatex-chicago}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\DeclareFieldFormat{pages}{%
  \iftoggle{cms@comprange}%
    {\mkcomprange[{\mkpageprefix[bookpagination]}]{#1}}%
    {\mkpageprefix[bookpagination]{#1}}}

\DeclareFieldFormat[article,periodical]{pages}{%
  \iftoggle{cms@comprange}%
    {\iffieldundef{bookpagination}%
       {\mkcomprange{#1}\isdot}%
       {\mkcomprange[{\mkpageprefix[bookpagination]}]{#1}}}%
    {\iffieldundef{bookpagination}%
       {#1\isdot}%
       {\mkpageprefix[bookpagination]{#1}}}}%

\begin{document}
\cite{sigfridsson,westfahl:space,gaonkar:in}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Gaonkar, Dilip Parameshwar. “On Alternative Modernities.” In Alternative Modernities, edited by Dilip Parameshwar Gaonkar, pp. 1–23. Durham and London: Duke University Press, 2001. isbn: 0-822-32714-7.//Sigfridsson, Emma, and Ulf Ryde. “Comparison of methods for deriving atomic charges from the electrostatic potential and moments.” Journal of Computational Chemistry 19, no. 4 (1998): 377–395. doi:10.1002/(SICI)1096-987X(199803)19:4<377::AID-JCC1>3.0.CO;2-P.//Westfahl, Gary. “The True Frontier: Confronting and Avoiding the Realities of Space in American Science Fiction Films.” In Space and Beyond: The Frontier Theme in Science Fiction, edited by Gary Westfahl, pp. 55–65. Westport, Conn. and London: Greenwood, 2000.]

---

If you are interested in getting the page prefix also in citations, you may want to add

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}{%
  \iftoggle{cms@comprange}%
    {\mkcomprange[{\mkpageprefix[pagination]}]{#1}}%
    {\mkpageprefix[pagination]{#1}}}%
```